# How to capture error of failed command with message using tee command

Tags: shell-script, error-handling, tee

I want to capture and write my error to log file along with custom message.

Consider the command :

```
$(find $val -type f -delete) || echo "error in deleting files" |tee -a log.txt
```

This command writes below line in log.txt file

```
error in deleting files
```

But I also want to print the error of find command to log filealong with my custom message , so that log file can look like this:

```
find: `/home/temp': No such file or directory
error in deleting files
```

Comment: Have you already seen [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159514/410261)? It could be useful to fully understand `||`

Comment: yes , I checked that answer , but I can't get around passing stderr to alternate command using || command. it never prints it to file. it just prints it to console , I can use >&2 to pass it to file , but I wanted to pass it to tee command for a unified structure of a big shell script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to alter the operators precedence there, and group the `find || echo` commands in a compound command redirected to the pipe to `tee`:

```bsh
{ $(find $val -type f -delete) || echo "error in deleting files"; } 2>&1 |tee -a log.txt
```

or also:

```bsh
($(find $val -type f -delete) || echo "error in deleting files") 2>&1 |tee -a log.txt
```

the `2>&1` redirection serves to redirect `find`'s error messages to the pipe read by `tee`, while `echo`'s output already goes naturally into that pipe.

Comment: oh , I was trying to redirect 2>&1 and then print the stdout to log with message , but this is more better, thanks